# I try to insert .2 to Oracle but it shows 0.2 in db

Tags: oracle

I am trying to add value .2 to db, but it shows 0.2 after inserting. The datatype is number(3,2). What can I do, so it not add leading zero to the decimal numbers.

Comment: That's the same value.  The *display* is just showing a leading zero when you read the value.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Hi David, is it possible not to add/display leading zero?

Comment: Sure, in your application code where you display the value.  If you're just viewing the data in 3rd party tools (like an Oracle application of some kind) then you'll see whatever that tool's display logic shows you.  *In the data*, `.2` and `0.2` are the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

A `NUMBER` is a binary data-type that stores an exact representation of the value by storing the pairs of digits in each byte and it **NEVER** stores the number with a particular formatting.

The number `.2` is exactly the same as the number `0.2` as they both have zero units and 2 tenths; the only difference is in how you want to format the value but the database does not store formatting with a `NUMBER`.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value NUMBER(3,2));

INSERT INTO table_name (value)
SELECT .2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT .20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0.20 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT value, DUMP(value) FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | DUMP(VALUE) |
| --- | --- |
| .2 | Typ=2 Len=2: 192,21 |
| .2 | Typ=2 Len=2: 192,21 |
| .2 | Typ=2 Len=2: 192,21 |
| .2 | Typ=2 Len=2: 192,21 |

and you can see that all the rows are identical and are stored with the same byte values.

---

If you want to format the number in a particular way then use `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(.2, '9.99'),
       TO_CHAR(.2, 'FM9.99'),
       TO_CHAR(.2, 'FM9.00'),
       TO_CHAR(.2, 'FM0.00')
FROM   DUAL
```

| TO_CHAR(.2,'9.99') | TO_CHAR(.2,'FM9.99') | TO_CHAR(.2,'FM9.00') | TO_CHAR(.2,'FM0.00') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .20 | .2 | .20 | 0.20 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EhpBQFh-)